# turning a local directory into a svn repo

Tags: svn

I found this tutorial : http://masstransmit.com/garage_blog/create-svn-existing-project/

But Im stuck in step 3

What I did was this :

1. `svnadmin create /root/cinnamon-for-crux`
2. `svn import /root/cinnamon file:///root/cinnamon-for-crux`

Now step 3 schould be according to the tutorial: `svn co /root/cinnamon-for-crux`. 
but then I get a message wrong arguments.

Anyone who can tell me how I can make this work so cinnamon-for-crux will be a svn repo with all the data and the contents of cinnamon in it?

Edit 1: So `svn co file:///cinnamon-for-crux` schould work

Edit 2: If I did the command from edit 1 `svn co file://cinnamon-for-crux` I see these error messages:

```
svn: E1800001: Unable to connect to a repo at url 'file:///cinnamon-for-crux' 
svn : E1800001 : Unable to open a ra-local session to URL
svn: E1800001: Unable to open repo at url 'file:///cinnamon-for-crux
```

Edit 3: it works. Can anyone tell me what the command is to upload the local tree to my page on googlecode ?

Comment: Do you get `svn: E205000: Error parsing arguments` by chance? Error messages **are** important, always quote them properly.

Comment: `/cinnamon-for-crux` != `/root/cinnamon-for-crux`

Answer (score 2):

Repository paths are always URLs. You need to use `file:///root/cinnamon-for-crux`.